# Will it be good to accept an answer when I found other solution?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

In stackoverflow.com, is it better to accept an answer even if I found other solution? or just leave it?

Comment: Belongs on meta.

Comment: This would be better on meta.stackoverflow.com, but you should add an answer yourself and accept it, so that other people with the same problem can find the answer more easily.

Comment: Why not post the solution that worked and then accept it as the answer(including a reference to the original solution)? That way anyone else who finds your question useful will also find the answer. Unanswered questions that *are* solved are bad for others who have the same question.

Comment: I'm relatively new to stackoverflow.com and I didn't know that meta existed

Answer (score 4):

As commenters have said:

Once you've found a solution yourself, you can always answer the question yourself and then (after a delay - 24 hours, I believe) accept your own answer.  You should also definitely include references to whatever materials you used to determine the solution, so that others can learn from it as well.

You definitely should not accept an answer that you don't feel is accurate or favorable.